# SIP Client (Peers) - Call received failed

Tags: sip, sip-server

I have to integrate the text, voice and video chat via SIP server into my application. So that I have chosen the "Peers" from http://peers.sourceforge.net/.

I have downloaded the code, registered a sip addressz(peers sip client) and call to another sip account(peers sip client). I can't receive a call in that peers client. If I call to another sip client(X-Lite), I can able to receive a call.

Can anybody tell me what may be the problem and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to call a remote party from peers you should use sip:user@domain.com where domain.com is the domain you used in your account. If you used an ip address in domain in your sip account, you should use the same domain.